# Error while deploying the Spring Boot app using Redis server in Tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, redis, tomcat9

I have a web application based on **Spring boot** (2.1.9.RELEASE) and using **Redis** server (Redis-x64-3.2.100 running as service) for Session attributes storage

The deployment in **Eclipse** as Spring Boot App goes well, the application can connect to Redis server and we can store/retrieve Session attributes

But when I wanted to deploy in **Tomcat** (version 9), I faced a problem linked to redis api in springframework :

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:
when resolving method "io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(Lorg/reactivestreams/Publisher;)Lio/reactivex/Flowable;"
the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) of the current class,
org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader)
for the method's defining class, io/reactivex/Flowable, have different Class objects for the type org/reactivestreams/Publisher used in the signature
```

Given that I have set all required configuration in Tomcat server, in context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink name="bean/redisson"
              global="bean/redisson"
      type="org.redisson.api.RedissonClient" />

<Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.JndiRedissonSessionManager"
     readMode="REDIS"
     jndiName="bean/redisson" />
<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->
<Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager"
  configPath="${catalina.base}/conf/redisson.yaml" 
  readMode="REDIS" updateMode="DEFAULT" broadcastSessionEvents="false"/>
```

Change in server.xml:

```
<Resource name="bean/redisson"
      auth="Container"
          factory="org.redisson.JndiRedissonFactory"
          configPath="${catalina.base}/conf/redisson.yaml"
      closeMethod="shutdown"/>
```

The redisson.yaml contains:

```
singleServerConfig:
  idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  connectTimeout: 10000
  timeout: 3000
  retryAttempts: 3
  retryInterval: 1500
  password: null
  subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
  clientName: null
  address: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
  subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
  subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
  connectionMinimumIdleSize: 24
  connectionPoolSize: 64
  database: 0
  dnsMonitoringInterval: 5000
threads: 16
nettyThreads: 32
codec: !<org.redisson.codec.FstCodec> {}
transportMode: "NIO"
```

And I put redisson-all-3.11.6.jar and redisson-tomcat-9-3.11.6.jar in Tomcat lib folder

Is the problem about redis vs Tomcat compatibility ? Did I miss something ? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long examination of the issue, discovered that there are conflicts between Redis libraries and Tomcat server internal libraries

At the end, I decided to switch the session storage to JDBC and discard completely Redis :

**In application.properties file**

- Set the app property spring.session.store-type=jdbc
- Set the app property spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
- Set the app property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none (create schema directly from an sql script)

**In schema.sql file**

Add two tables managing the session:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON MATFRONT.SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON MATFRONT.SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON MATFRONT.SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES BLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES MATFRONT.SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Thanks to that, I got rid of an additional entire server used only for storing session data

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly stated:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
```

Please read about `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` This basically is telling you that it can't find this method at run-time. You have to do below steps:

1. Figure out which library (jar) file has this method, verify method signature.
2. Ensure that this library is part of your classpath, i.e. should be part of your maven or gradle file.
3. Check for a conflict. If you have any other jar file which also provides the same class, i.e. RedisConnection then you have to remove that redundant jar file.

Basically, the error is coming because the program is invoking the RedisConnection class but is not able to find the getConfig method (same signature) in that class.
My guess is you have two conflicting libraries and is invoking the wrong one. You have to remove or clean up the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your help !, as you suggested, I did the research and I have found a mismatch of a constructor of a class between two libraries (Redis vs Tomcat), finally i have decided to use JDBC storage instead, I added an answer on this matter